# How can I refresh an EJS partial with updated data every few seconds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to update the content of an ejs partial every 5 seconds with new data obtained from a fetch request. I want to avoid rewriting each line of the partial and instead just update the content within it. However, I am not sure how to call setInterval to re-render the partial.

This is my get route:

```
app.get("/tracker", async (req, res) => {
  const response = await fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d");
  const listings = await response.json();

  if (req.user) {
    req.session.user = req.user;
  } else {
    req.session.user = null;
  }
  const user = req.session.user;

  res.render("./index", { listings, user });
});
```

And this is a section of the Index EJS file it renders:

```
 <tbody id="listings">
      <!-- Create token/coin listing -->
      <%- include ('./partials/list', { listings }) %>
  </tbody>
```

Then this is the partial that gets called:

```
<% for (let item of listings) { %>
<form action="/<%=item.market_cap_rank%>/favorites?_method=PUT" method="POST">
  <tr>
    <td class="rank text-center pb-3"><%=item.market_cap_rank%></td>
    <td class="text-center pb-3 image-cell">
      <img src="<%=item.image%>" alt="" class="item-image" />
    </td>
    <td class="name text-center pb-3">
      <a href="https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/<%=item.id%>" class="item-link"><%=item.name%> (<%=item.symbol%>)</a>
    </td>
    <td class="price text-center pb-3">
      <% if(item.current_price > 0.01) { %>
      <!-- If current price is more than .01, only display 2 decimal points -->
      $<%=item.current_price.toFixed(2)%> <% } else { %>
      <!-- Else display all the decimal points -->
      $<%=item.current_price%> <% } %>
    </td>
    <td class="change text-center pb-3 ps-5 pe-5"><%=item.price_change_percentage_24h_in_currency.toFixed(2)%> %</td>
  </tr>
</form>
<% } %>
```

I started off trying this and found out setInterval cannot be used in EJS like this:

```
<tbody>
  <% setInterval((listings) => { %>
  <!-- Create token/coin listing -->
  <%- include ('./partials/list', { listings }) %>
  <% }, 5000) %>
</tbody>
```

I now currently have a separate file that clears the html of the table and appends the new data back to it. For some reason it only lists every odd item after 3 or 4 intervals though. I would also prefer to just re-render the partial instead of recreating the table each time.

```
async function updateList() {
  console.log("test");
  await fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d")
    .then(async (response) => await response.json())
    .then(async (newListings) => {
      // Clear the existing rows from the table
      const imageTds = document.querySelectorAll(".image-cell");
      await imageTds.forEach((td) => {
        td.innerHTML = "";
      });

      const nameTds = document.querySelectorAll(".name");
      await nameTds.forEach((td) => {
        td.innerHTML = "";
      });

      const priceTds = document.querySelectorAll(".price");
      await priceTds.forEach((td) => {
        td.innerHTML = "";
      });

      const changeTds = document.querySelectorAll(".change");
      await changeTds.forEach((td) => {
        td.innerHTML = "";
      });

      console.log(newListings);

      await newListings.forEach((item, i) => {
        const tr = document.createElement("tr");

        const imageTd = document.createElement("td");
        imageTd.classList.add("text-center", "pb-3", "image-cell");
        const image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = item.image;
        image.alt = "";
        image.classList.add("item-image");
        imageTd.appendChild(image);
        imageTds[i].append(imageTd);

        const nameTd = document.createElement("td");
        nameTd.classList.add("name", "text-center", "pb-3");
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = `https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/${item.id}`;
        link.classList.add("item-link");
        link.textContent = `${item.name} (${item.symbol})`;
        nameTd.appendChild(link);
        nameTds[i].append(nameTd);

        const priceTd = document.createElement("td");
        priceTd.classList.add("price", "text-center", "pb-3");
        if (item.current_price > 0.01) {
          priceTd.textContent = `$${item.current_price.toFixed(2)}`;
        } else {
          priceTd.textContent = `$${item.current_price}`;
        }
        priceTds[i].append(priceTd);

        const changeTd = document.createElement("td");
        changeTd.classList.add("change", "text-center", "pb-3", "ps-5", "pe-5");
        changeTd.textContent = item.price_change_percentage_24h_in_currency.toFixed(2);
        changeTds[i].append(changeTd);

        tr.append(imageTds, nameTds, priceTds, changeTds);
      });
    });
}

module.exports = updateList;
```

I also found an answer here using the meta tag, but that refreshes the entire page when I just want the data of the table to refresh.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```